# Using redirect gets 404 error with memcache

Tags: redirect, joomla, memcached

I'm developing a site with Joomla and am doing a homepage redirect if a user is already logged in. It works like a champ, however if I enable memcache it results in a 404 page.

Here's the simple code I'm using:
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    if($user->guest){ }
    else {
     header("Location: index.php?option=com_comprofiler");
    }

Any idea why this is happening or better yet how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's [killing your session](http://docs.joomla.org/JSessionStorageMemcache/1.6), try using:

```
jimport( 'joomla.session.storage.memcache' );
```